# Handling an absence of Twitter in iOS

Tags: objective-c, twitter, ios5

If I am using Apple's Twitter API in an application and I discover that a user has not added any Twitter account to their Settings/Twitter, is there any better way to handle it other than showing them an alert telling them they need to add a Twitter account? It feels like there should be a nicer way to get them to add an account.

Answer (score 3):

The Settings app has a registered URL scheme for taking the user directly to any section. If you want to take the user directly to the Twitter login section of Settings, you would call this line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];
```

I would suggest showing an alert asking the user whether they would like to enter their Twitter account. If they say yes, use the above code to take them to the Twitter login screen.